# Hive ACID table locks deadlock never expires

Tags: hive, acid

Guess enabling ACID in hive is a lone route. I find it difficult to find a solution.

This query is also similar to the below one by me.

[Hive table does not respond to select query. ACID enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55298929/hive-table-does-not-respond-to-select-query-acid-enabled)

Error:
`FAILED: Error in acquiring locks: Lock acquisition for LockRequest(component:[
LockComponent(type:SHARED_READ, level:TABLE, dbname:db1, tablename:table1, operationType:INSERT, isAcid:true), 
LockComponent(type:SHARED_READ, level:TABLE, dbname:db1, tablename:table2, operationType:SELECT), 
LockComponent(type:SHARED_READ, level:TABLE, dbname:db1, tablename:table3, operationType:SELECT)], 
txnid:10140, user:userid, hostname:host.xyz.com, agentInfo:userid_20190707082237_ff87ff1b-bcc2-466d-b5db-e5781ff1f2ef)
 timed out after 5503292ms.  LockResponse(lockid:22084, state:WAITING)`

There are some locks present for months. Even after re-creating tables these locks are still present. which may be a reason for the error. 
But i am not sure. Because sometimes the same failing queries works too. Its confusing.

I use system command from R to run hive queries like below. So for every query below settings are also executed

```
acid <- "set hive.support.concurrency=true;
    set hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;
    set hive.enforce.bucketing=true;
    set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nostrict;
    set hive.compactor.initiator.on=true;
    set hive.compactor.worker.threads=1;"

hql <- paste(acid,hql)
response <- system(paste0("hive -S -e ","\"", hql,"\""," 2>&1"), wait = TRUE,intern=TRUE)
```

For few queries like `select count(*)` I use `tez` , because the query runs without issues and much faster. Not all queries can use `tez` because it gives some other errors.

Some `Drop table` queries gives lock time out. But the same `Drop table` works fine without enabling `ACID` properties.

I guess i could explain it correctly. And i know it is multiple issues. But the main issue is **Unable to execute queries because of locks. And unable to kill the locks as well.**

Hive version

`Hive 2.1.1-mapr-1803
Subversion git://9281ba475c39/root/opensource/mapr-hive-2.1/dl/mapr-hive-2.1 -r ef09bc4b4286a3f53947196a79949620b006344e
Compiled by root on Mon Apr 2 15:49:32 UTC 2018
From source with checksum e47dbe8554cd78b7254c1856508175bd`

Answer (score 0):

I also met a similar problem in hive3, and i read the source code in `org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.txn.TxnHandler`, i found that there is a function called `performTimeOuts()`, which is scheduled periodically by a daemon thread called `org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.txn.AcidHouseKeeperService`.

That daemon thread will clean outdated lock infomation automatically in the mysql table `hive.hive_locks`, but it is not enabled by default, so we just need to configure it in hive-site.xml, like this:

```
<property>
    <name>metastore.task.threads.always</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.events.EventCleanerTask,org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RuntimeStatsCleanerTask,org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.repl.DumpDirCleanerTask,org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.txn.AcidHouseKeeperService</value>
</property>
```

Or you can delete some rows related to your sql table in `hive.hive_locks` from mysql, i truncated that mysql table at the first time, and that worked.