# Exclusive lock at Hive Table has not got released automatically when hive services restart in between

Tags: hive, hiveql, deadlock, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

While running Insert command `INSERT INTO TABLE xyz PARTITION(partition_date='2020-02-28') values('A',123, 'C',45).....` or `Alter table drop partition (alter table  xyz  drop if exists partition(partition_date='2020-02-28');` command in hive, if hive services got restarted in between through ambari or due to any unwanted scenario, then that acquired the exclusive lock on that partition which will remains after the restart also and for that kind of job there is no yarn application id is generated sometimes and if generated then it also got succeeded but exclusive locks remains on that table or partition, which later we have to manually released from the table or partitioned.

[image: Exclusive Lock after Restart]

So why these locks remains on that partition or table and how these kind of scenarios can be handle at our end?

Is there any workaround for these kind of scenarios?

Comment: You can run any number of HS2 instances in parallel _( High Availibility is achieved via an active/active setup)_. An instance cannot remove existing locks on startup, because they might be used by other instances -- which makes automatic cleanup impossible.

Comment: Locks may be left dangling in ZooKeeper case of crash, or because of a bug. This happens. Solutions: (1) wait until they expire -- cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-Locking for how to tune the lifetime of a lock (2) remove the locks manually in ZooKeeper when needed (3) disable the locking mechanism altogether, if you want to live dangerously (Spark and Impala and Presto don't care about locks anyway so the danger is already there)

Answer (score -1):

I met a similar problem and resolved it, there are two ways:
(1) The hive lock information is stored at a mysql table called `hive.hive_locks`, so you can delete relevant rows about your sql table, or truncate that table. But this way cannot fix the problem permanently.

(2) Add a configuration in `hive-site.xml`, just like this:

```
<property>
    <name>metastore.task.threads.always</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.events.EventCleanerTask,org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RuntimeStatsCleanerTask,org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.repl.DumpDirCleanerTask,org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.txn.AcidHouseKeeperService</value>
</property>
```

You can also refer to the answer on this question, i made a detailed explanation about the second way:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73771475/9120595